# Are there any major library fires reported for the middle ages?

Tags: middle-ages, book

With nearly all books made from parchment, I wonder if anything combustible was around after papyrus was phased out and paper not in use yet.

Comment: There is the alleged [destruction of the Library of Alexandria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destruction_of_the_Library_of_Alexandria#Muslim_conquest_of_Egypt) on the orders of the Caliph in the 7th century.

Comment: It is worth noting that parchment does burn, as evidenced with what happened to the [Cotton manuscript collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotton_library#Ashburnham_House_fire) in 1731. There is a [List of destroyed libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_destroyed_libraries) on Wikipedia which includes some destroyed by fire (both deliberate and accidental).

Comment: If parchment does burn, then ofcourse the question is pointless. But isn't it leather, as is used in e.g fireproof clothing?

Comment: It's the same basic material, but Parchment has been subjected to different treatments and is much thinner than the leather used to protect against fire - and even that will burn eventually! There's more information on the fire that damaged the Cotton collection, and the efforts made by conservators to save them, on the [British Library Manuscripts Blog](http://blogs.bl.uk/digitisedmanuscripts/2016/10/fire-fire-the-tragic-burning-of-the-cotton-library.html)

Comment: @sempaiscuba-  I tested this, and indeed parchment does burn. It flames out fast thouog. Because of the cost of the stuff, i dit not test densely packed stacks of it.